# How can I update the Android of my Tablet? (TITAN Android 4.0.3) It is root

Tags: rom-flashing

I need help to install another ROM...

The tablet says the model is 720F, but in the back cover it says PC7010ME (?)

I'm confused... It doesn't have Home button. It has ESC; On/Off; M (Menu) key.  The home button (along with Back and Options) is in the OS.

[image: This is what shows the "About tablet"]

[image: This is the back of the device]

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, if that helps somehow..

(First time performing this ROM process)

Comment: In general, you can't... This is one of those "generic" Chinese tablets that was never well supported. The only way to upgrade is with a custom ROM, but a quick Google search shows none exist. ROM's are extremely model/variant dependent, so if there isn't one specifically for your device, you can't upgrade it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is obviously some generic Chinese knockoff Android tablet, upgrading it is near impossible if the manufacturer never released a new update (as they never do). If you were hoping to go down the custom ROM path, well you still can't upgrade it as a custom ROM simply doesn't exist.b No one wants to spend time and effort to develop for such a erm... "niche" device.